# How to create new record in rails app using postgresql db with postgis extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I am developing a rails app and my database is postgresql. I added postgis extension to it and I have a model **Pipe** with one attribute **location** that is type **geometry**. I need to add new records now I don't know how. I tried:

```
Pipe.create(location: "line_string(2.439418, 19.253800, 2.439418, 19.25381, 2.439418,    19.253815, 2.439418, 19.2539"))
```

Help with this syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to make [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) (WKT), which when properly formatted would be:

```
LINESTRING (2.439418 19.2538, 2.439418 19.25381, 2.439418 19.253815, 2.439418 19.2539)
```

Comment: I see. But my line still doesn't work with that, I still get syntax error and can't create anything.

Comment: There was something wrong with my postgis extension. I reinstalled postgis and now this works fine. Thanks!

`Pipe.create(location: "LINESTRING(2.439418 19.2538, 2.439418 19.25381, 2.439418 19.253815, 2.439418 19.2539)")`